# Font Awesome sizing does not work - icon shows as small but the 'clickable' area is big

Tags: html, css, icons, size, font-awesome

I have added in my font awesome html and css but when running it on a browser, the icons look tiny however it seems as if the actual icon size is big as expected as they are clickable in a larger area around each of the icons.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krjmC.png)

```css
.social a {
  font-size: 7.5em !important;
  padding: 3rem;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container-fluid padding">
  <div class="row text-center padding">
   <div class="col-12">
    <h2>Connect</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12 social padding">
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS is targeting the link element and not the icons

You need to change your CSS to

```
.social i {
  font-size: 7.5em !important;
  padding: 3rem;
}
```

```css
.social i {
  font-size: 7.5em !important;
  padding: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid padding">
  <div class="row text-center padding">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h2>Connect</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 social padding">
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I have made the change but the icons now are together with no spacing and yet the font size does not change no matter what size i put in it.

Comment: Can you share the changes you've made? I've added an example to the answer which works when I try it